# I want to make automatic image slider in HTML, I tried but that doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image slider of width:100% and height 365%
I tried this but its not working.`

```
<style>
    .slide{
        width: 100%;
        height: 370px;
        border: 2px solid orange;
        animation-name: slide1;
        animation-duration: 8s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @keyframes slide1{
        0%{
            /* background-color: orange; */
            background-image: url("3.jpg");
        }
        25%{
            background-image: url("a2.img");
        }
        75%{
            background-image: url("a3.img");
        }
        100%{
            background-image: url("a4.img");
        }
    }
</style>
```

and in the body If I add that much I hope that it should work

```
<body>
<div class="slide">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please explain "what's not working"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I think you've missed `animation-timing-function`.

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  animation-name: slide1;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes slide1 {
  0% {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633113215844-b2ddc0411724?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637709569303-f7cda15a4d3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637717256696-a0204d03a8fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633113215844-b2ddc0411724?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</body>
```